# Merge several columns into 1 column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

i have a question regarding data.table package in R.
Now i have a data like this

```
a=data.table(person=c(1:3),grade=c(4:6),age=(30:32))
a

   person grade age
1:      1     4  30
2:      2     5  31
3:      3     6  32
```

Now i want to generate a new data which merge the amount of grade and age into one column, and we will have criteria column next to it, like this

```
   person criteria amount
1:      1    grade      4
2:      2    grade      5
3:      3    grade      6
4:      1      age     30
5:      2      age     31
6:      3      age     32
```

Do you know how could i achieve that in data.table. Thanks so much

Comment: Look at the `melt` function.

Comment: Thanks. great advice